# Solving this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I need help finding a closed-form solution to 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n^{2}+p\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

This came up when I was doing some physics, and I could not find any solution. I do not have enough education to solve it myself and analysis with Wolfram alpha yeilded no results.

Comment: you might want to look up the various ways one can find closed forms of these infinite series by contour integrating cleverly selected functions.

Comment: if $p = 0$ you have Apery's constant.  There is no exact representation for this.  So, I doubt you will get one for any other value of $p.$

Comment: @DougM I would think so too, but when I did the same sort of sum without the 3/2 exponent, ζ(2) appeared in the solution, but it was simply a constant. The argument to the zeta term never changed.

Comment: Assuming $p>0$, that is $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s}{e^s-1}\cdot\frac{J_1(s\sqrt{p})}{\sqrt{p}}\,ds$$ by the inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 2):

As said, no closed form can be expected.

But since this seems to be for physics, I think that we could have rather good approximations of the summation  using the simplistic and totally empirical model
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n^{2}+p\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sim \frac {a+b\,p}{1+c\, p}$$ Fitted over the range $0 \leq p \leq 100$, with $R^2=0.999976$ we should have
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.20359 & 0.00360 & \{1.19645,1.21074\} \\
 b & 0.00148 & 0.00008 & \{0.00132,0.00164\} \\
 c & 1.35552 & 0.00587 & \{1.34387,1.36717\} \\
\end{array}$$
A better approximation $(R^2 > 0.999999)$ would be 
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n^{2}+p\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sim \frac {a+b\,p}{1+c\, p+d \, p^2}$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.25144 & 0.00039 & \{1.25065,1.25222\} \\
 b & 0.08231 & 0.00083 & \{0.08067,0.08395\} \\
 c & 1.51799 & 0.00141 & \{1.51520,1.52078\} \\
 d & 0.08470 & 0.00088 & \{0.08296,0.08644\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Elvin. Sorry but I do not use LaTex (only MathJax on this site). Have a look at https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php I hope it could help you.